# Select all rows in exjs infinite grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, selection, infinite

I want to select any row in the `infinite grid` by code. The method `grid.getSelectionModel().selectAll()` doesn't work. When I try to loop through the rows and select the rows with `grid.getSelectionModel().select(i, true)` it works fine for the first 1000 rows. After that, it stops (I guess because of the buffering?).

```
 for (var i = 0; i < store.getTotalCount(); i++) {
     me.getGrid().getSelectionModel().select(i, true);
 }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The point of the infinite grid is to load batches of data on demand, and not the entire set. What do you want to do next, assuming that you've selected all records?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
me.getGrid().getSelectionModel().selectAll();
```

For this You have to set grid config as below:

```
selModel: {
mode: 'MULTI'
}
```

There is one article related to ExtJs6 infinite grid issue, you will get workaround:

[Extjs6 infinite grid selection issue](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?232898-Selection-disappears-when-scolling-in-an-infinite-grid)

Comment: selModel looks like this:

`selModel: {
        mode: 'MULTI',//'SIMPLE',
        multiSelect: true,
        pruneRemoved: false
    },`

Maybe the problem is that I use Extjs 4.2.3?

Comment: There is no such version issue for this. We are using this code from Extjs 4 version.